# How to convert data to string

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have data for example like this:

```
data: [{
  tag: 'Apple',
}, {
  tag: 'Microsoft',
}, {
  tag: 'Google',
}]
```

And I want to convert them into like this:

```
data: ['Apple','Microsoft','Google']
```

Is there a best way to do this? Wherever I am reading, people are using complex logic using loops. So are there alternative methods to doing this?

Comment: Depends on the programming language.

Comment: i want to do it via javascript

Comment: If you want to hide or convert the `tag` part, you need to use a loop and change it yourself. If you want to just show the element you print it using `JSON.stringify(myObj)`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: data.map(obj => obj.tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use [**Array.map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and replace the object `ele.tag` with just the value `return ele.tag`:

```js
var data =
[{
  tag: 'Apple',
}, {
  tag: 'Microsoft',
}, {
  tag: 'Google',
}];

data = data.map(function(ele){ return ele.tag; });

console.log(data);
```

Or in ES6 you can simply this even more:

```
data = data.map(ele => ele.tag);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for-in loop and push the attribute of the object into an array.

```js
var data = [{
  tag: 'Apple',
}, {
  tag: 'Microsoft',
}, {
  tag: 'Google',
}];

var tags = [];
for (prop in data) {
  tags.push(data[prop].tag);
}

console.log(tags);
```

Answer (score 0):

For easier handling let's take the object in the OP's code and assign it to a variable, as follows:

```js
var obj =  {"data":[{"tag":'Apple'},{"tag":'Microsoft'},{"tag":'Google'}]};   
var {data}= obj; // object destructing ...
var mapped = data.map(function( e ){ return e.tag}); 

// re-assigning value of object's data property
obj["data"] = mapped; 

console.log(obj);     // obj.data now pertains to array of strings
```

The problem described by the OP involves an object whose data *property* refers to an array of objects, each with a tag property. The OP inquires as to how to revise the data property so that it refers instead to an array of string values corresponding to each object's tag property.

This example makes use of [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to access the array of objects. Then, it uses the array's map() method to access every element's tag property and thereby obtain its string value.  The beauty of map() is that it performs iteration *behind the scenes* sparing the user from having to hand-code a loop with the correct logic -- although in functional programming languages instead of using iteration, recursion is more apt to be utilized for this purpose. Finally, the value of the object's data property is reset to contain the specified array of strings.